# Stripe integration in Kotlin App -- IllegalStateException

Tags: java, date, kotlin, stripe-payments, illegalstateexception

I am integrating Stripe for Java in a Kotlin app.

This is the code that I wrote to [`create a Charge`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create)

createCharge function:

```
fun createCharge(charge: Charge, testApiKey: String): Charge? {
        //met

        // On your server, grab the Stripe token in the POST parameters submitted by your form. From there, it’s one simple API call to charge the card
        Stripe.apiKey = testApiKey

        try {
            val chargeParams = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()

            chargeParams["amount"] = charge.amount
            chargeParams["currency"] = charge.currency
            chargeParams["description"] = charge.description
            chargeParams["source"] = charge.source
            chargeParams["customer"] = charge.customer
            chargeParams["receipt_email"] = charge.receiptEmail

            val requestOptions = idempotencyKeySetter()

            val initialMetadata = mutableMapOf<String, String?>()
            initialMetadata["start_date"] = charge.metadata["start_date"]
            initialMetadata["end_date"] = charge.metadata["end_date"]

            chargeParams["metadata"] = initialMetadata

            return Charge.create(chargeParams, requestOptions)

        } catch (e: StripeException) {

            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }
    }
```

and the function calling the createCharge function:

```
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
fun checkCreateCharge() {
        val chargeParams: Charge = Charge()

        chargeParams.amount = 2000
        chargeParams.currency = "usd"
        chargeParams.description = description
        chargeParams.source = PaymentSource { "" }
        chargeParams.customer = customerId
        chargeParams.receiptEmail = testEmail

        chargeParams.metadata["start_date"] = LocalDate.parse("2018-12-31", formatter).toString()
        chargeParams.metadata["end_date"] = LocalDate.parse("2019-03-31", formatter).toString()

        val newCharge: Charge? = createCharge(chargeParams, testApiKey)
    }
```

When I the function `checkCreateCharge` runs, it sends the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: chargeParams.metadata must not be null`

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

So while this is "possible" you absolutely should not do this. It's a very large security vulnerability. Anyone with your App would be able to sniff your Stripe Secret API Key and do any number of bad things. They could, for instance, test credit cards or even take money from your account.

When implementing Stripe on Android you should *only* use your Publishable API Key and only use the key to create Tokens/Sources. All other operations should leverage your Secret API Key on a secured backend.

Comment: I just started writing this yesterday and haven't thought about the security aspect of it yet. I will obviously not be using this code in production. I just want to `create a charge` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell from the API documentation, you're accessing `getMetadata()` which is returning null (as you've never set a value on it). Basically, the line:

```
chargeParams.metadata["start_date"] = LocalDate.parse("2018-12-31", formatter).toString()
```

is equivalent to the Java code:

```
chargeParams.getMetadata().put("start_date", LocalDate.parse("2018-12-31", formatter).toString())
```

and in your situation `getMetadata()` is null. I believe changing this to be:

```
chargeParams.setMetadata(
    mapOf(
        "start_date" to LocalDate.parse("2018-12-31", formatter).toString(),
        "end_date" to LocalDate.parse("2019-03-31", formatter).toString()
    )
)
```

will resolve the issue.